# Prompt User my mobile app when Opening Location link through WhatsApp

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation, location

I want to list my app when a user clicks on link shared over Whatsapp or any other app.

I have developed my app using xamarin forms. I'm looking this solution primarily for an Android platform.

Attached is the screenshot for the reference.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkpdB.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry for can not seeing the screenshot, could you update it in question again?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Because not seeing the shared screenshot, I'm not sure whether it's your wants.

There is a **[Xamarin.Essentials: Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)** that can list the installed app and share *text/uri/file* to them.

Add a reference to Xamarin.Essentials in your class:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
```

Share text:

```
public async Task ShareText(string text)
{
    await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
        {
            Text = text,
            Title = "Share Text"
        });
}
```

Share uri:

```
public async Task ShareUri(string uri)
{
    await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
        {
            Uri = uri,
            Title = "Share Web Link"
        });
}
```

Share file:

```
var fn =  "Attachment.txt";
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");

await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
    Title = Title,
    File = new ShareFile(file)
});
```